# How do i pass object of my own class between activity

Tags: android

I want to pass an object to a new activity
from MainActivity

```
NetworkHandler nH=new NetworkHandler();
```

`nH` is my own created class i want to send this object to a new activity

Comment: use  Parcelable interface. Refer :https://coderwall.com/p/vfbing/passing-objects-between-activities-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if NetworkHandler  is Serializable you can serialize object and pass it to another Activity

```
class NetworkHandler implements Serializable{
....
}
```

and pass it to another activity in this way

```
   Bundle bundleObject = new Bundle();
                            Intent i = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
    bundleObject.putSerializable(KEY, (Serializable) new NetworkHandler ());
    i.putExtras(bundleObject);
    startActivity(i);
```

in second activity onCreate get objet

```
Bundle bundleObject = getIntent().getExtras();
NetworkHandler  nh = (NetworkHandler) 
                            bundleObject.getSerializable
                                (KEY);
```

You can also Implement Parcelable interface to NetworkHandler.

Comment: See also:
http://sohailaziz05.blogspot.com/2012/04/passing-custom-objects-between-android.html

Answer (score 1):

Two possible answers

1. **You Can't:** Because you can't pass objects from one activity to another (until and unless it is Parcelable) in android
2. **You Can:** You can use `shared preferences` to pass primitive data from one activity to another OR you can use single instance (singleton) class to set/get `objects` from one place to another.

Comment: we can use Parcelable to pass object between activities. Or there is anything else therefore you are saying You Can't.

Comment: I am assuming the user is naive or beginner. Of course we can use Parcelable objects.

Comment: Ok, Thanks I thought there is some other reason behind that.

Answer (score 0):

When starting new activity, your intent can carry data:

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
}
```

The problem is, that intent can carry only primitive, `Serializable` or `Parcelable` data types. If you have non-serializable objects, like network sockets, you can't send them via `Intent` extras. In such case you may want to start a `Service` holding your complex data (sockets, resource handlers, etc) and bind to that service in new activity.

Check out those resources:

- http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 0):

If it is to do with network it should really be on its own thread.

However I would probably keep a handle to it in the `application` of my app, that way it can be used on all activities.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that extends Application class and create a singleton of that object inside it. This way you can access this object in all of your activity.

```
public class GlobalClass extends Application {

    NetworkHandler nH = null;

        public NetworkHandler getNetworkHandler() {
        if (nH == null) {
            nH = new NetworkHandler();
        }
        return nH;
    }
}
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml mention the name your class

```
<application
    android:name=".GlobalClass " >
```

You can access this object in any class using following code.

```
GlobalClass gObj = (GlobalClass) this.getApplication();

NetworkHandler nH = gObj.getNetworkHandler()
```